# How to run this ActiveJ program/project after done with Maven build steps?

Tags: java, maven

I'm learning ActiveJ from the official tutorial (https://activej.io/tutorials/getting-started#1-create-from-maven-archetype)

I'm stuck trying to "Open WebApp and run its main method".[image]

I completed the preceding steps - it says build success.

I don't understand what it means by "open WebApp and run its main method" - the statement was too vague to me. I tried the command "java WebApp" within the directory where `WebApp.class` resides, but it doesn't work.

I tried `mvn package`, and ran the command "java {yourClassHere}" thing.

I expect the documentation to be more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

You should know your main class to run your generated ActiveJ web app. Let's say your main class name is `org.example.WebApp`, then you can use the following maven command to run the application.

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.example.WebApp"
```

The above command will compile your application and start your web application in the `http://localhost:8080/` URL. Open the URL in your browser.